# theme_field() render array

Tags: theming

I hoped the documentation for [theme_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7) would tell me how to create a render array that may be parsed by that function.

Based on that, I thought something like this would work.

```
return array(
    'test' => array(
        '#theme' => 'field',
        '#label_hidden' =>  false,
        '#title_attributes' => 'class="test123"',
        '#label' => 'test',
        '#content_attributes' => 'class="test456"',
        '#items' => array()
    )
);
```

It prints a `&nbsp;`.

what am I doing wrong?

The ultimate goal is of course printing some field_items, but I can find no documentation on how the render array for #items should look; nothing I tried outputs anything.

A pointer to better documentation might answer my questions.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this manually? The API has functions to prepare fields for you (`field_view_field`, `field_view_value`, etc.), it'd be far easier to use those to prepare your fields

Comment: I dont want to display drupal database fields, but custom data from a remote api. For consistency, I want it rendered on the front end 'as if it were drupal items'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely *need* to piggyback on `theme_field()` rather than implement your own theme function (which would be preferable IMHO), then you'll have to jump through a few more hoops.

The key place to look is [`template_preprocess_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7), which will show you all of the elements that are expected to be in the array. Specifically for the label, the `#title` property is used. So this

```
return array(
  'test' => array(
    '#theme'                => 'field',
    '#label_hidden'         =>  false,
    '#title_attributes'     => 'class="test123"',
    '#label'                => 'test',
    '#title' => 'test',  // Required
    '#label_display' => 'visible',  // Required
    '#content_attributes'   => 'class="test456"',
    '#items'    => array()
  )
);
```

will return what you're looking for (with a bunch of notices about undefined indicies).

Eventually you'll also need to provide `#field_name`, `#field_type`, `#bundle` and `#entity_type` for each of your 'field' items.

Comment: excellent, that worked. i still cant get data to show up for the fields .. but since I'm going to have to fake a #bundle name and #field_type, indeed maybe this is not the way to go.